How to add Done button on keyboard on iOS in react-native
I'm working on a React Native app and I need to add a "Done" button above the iOS keyboard. The goal is to provide users with an easy way to dismiss the keyboard after they finish typing, instead of relying on the default behavior.
I want the button to appear right above the keyboard, similar to a custom toolbar. When the user taps "Done," the keyboard should close. I'm specifically looking for a solution that works only for iOS, since iOS allows adding custom input accessory views.
I'm looking for a solution that would achieve something like this:


To add a "Done" button above the keyboard on iOS in React Native, you can use the native iOS component InputAccessoryView. This allows you to display custom views, like buttons, directly above the keyboard.
Here's how you can achieve this using the inputAccessoryViewID prop to link your input field to the accessory view:
Solution:
Assign a unique inputAccessoryViewID to your input field.
Use InputAccessoryView to add a custom "Done" button, which dismisses the keyboard when pressed.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button, InputAccessoryView, Keyboard, Platform } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const inputAccessoryViewID = 'uniqueID'; // Unique ID for accessory view

  const handleDonePress = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss(); // Dismiss the keyboard when the Done button is pressed
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', padding: 20 }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          height: 40,
          borderColor: 'gray',
          borderWidth: 1,
          padding: 10,
          marginBottom: 20
        }}
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={setInputValue}
        placeholder="Enter text"
        returnKeyType="done"
        inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID} // Link input to accessory view
      />

      {/* InputAccessoryView for iOS */}
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
        <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgray', padding: 10, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
            <Button onPress={handleDonePress} title="Done" />
          </View>
        </InputAccessoryView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

